# acumatica and zpl label printing

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to create a zpl file and send it to a thermal printer automatically from the report designer? The use case is that we need to print "tags" for our stock and serial items. We have a custom output report and need to be able to send that as a zpl file format to a tag printer.

Comment: You can try to use Device Hub, if I am not wrong it allows to print raw data/text directly to printer

Answer (score 2):

Acumatica DeviceHub has a "raw mode" that's specially designed for label printers. I tested it extensively with Zebra printers and ZPL while working on the advanced fulfillment module.

[image: Printer Configuration in DeviceHub]

A [recent blog post by Sergey Marenich](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/10/send-documents-to-printers.html) talks about DeviceHub; you will not find any information on how to use the raw mode, but it does explain the basics of Device Hub, print queues and how to send a job. Device Hub is now part of Acumatica 2018 R2 (it used to be available as a separate download with the advanced fulfillment pre-release module) and from the Source Code browser you can find quite a few examples of where it is used, including this one from `SOShipmentEntry` that works with labels. `PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobForRawFile` is the function you need to call.

```
if (lableFiles.Count > 0)
                {
                    FileInfo mergedFile = MergeFiles(lableFiles);
                    if (upload.SaveFile(mergedFile))
                    {
                        if (PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.deviceHub>())
                            PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobForRawFile(adapter, new NotificationUtility(this).SearchPrinter, SONotificationSource.Customer, SOReports.PrintLabels, Accessinfo.BranchID, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FILEID", mergedFile.UID.ToString() } },
                                PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix(SOShipmentEntryActionsAttribute.Messages.PrintLabels, mergedFile.ToString()));

                        targetUrl = PXRedirectToFileException.BuildUrl(mergedFile.UID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new PXException(Messages.FailedToSaveMergedFile);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We will take a look but that actually leads me to another related question.  With device hub, it seems that you set up queues that can be selected from process screens when printing. Many of our use cases involve one off printing that doesn't run through the process screen. Do you know if it's possible (and how) to print to a queue without going through a process screen?

Comment: Sorry; I read the link you sent which has exactly this information. Many thanks. Will give this a try.

Comment: The pick/pack/ship screen of the advanced fulfillment is an example of real-time/interactive use of the print queues. It’s actually the primary reason why the tool was built. User profile is linked to a laser printer queue and a label printer queue and as shipments get confirmed, labels and packing slips print automatically. Printing from mass processing screens like you see in the app was added afterwards. You should be able to handle both use cases in your app.

Comment: Actually, sorry, but I have one other question. As of now, our reports are generated as pdf. But we realized that for a few of them, the printer expects zpl formats. Does the device hub "raw mode" handle the conversion? or do we need to explicitly create different format/output of a report?

Comment: You can definitely print from a PDF file but you would have to uncheck the "raw" mode option. For label printers I highly encourage you to use the ZPL format - performance will be day and night and the rendering quality will be better, especially if you have bar codes!

Comment: I apologise if this is an ignorant question, but do you know if we are able to simple change the PDF format to zpl ? Or do we have to completely rewrite the reports to accommodate the zpl format ?

Comment: ZPL is completely different than PDF (see http://labelary.com/viewer.html). Even if you managed to convert the PDF to ZPL it would probably be just an embedded image, nullifying any benefit of ZPL. Go straight with PDF in this case and spool it like you would for a laser printer with DeviceHub. P.S. If you're printing shipment labels, the carrier will provide you the ZPL files. Or you can use a specialized tool to generate it.

Comment: Hello Gabriel, I apologize if am wrong, for printing shipment labels, the carrier will provide ZPLfiles and these files are stored with its unique guid in the database and using this guid acumatica will allow us to print labels, but we have designed a report using report designer to print some tags which has barcodes, can you please guide us some direction on how we can achieve zpl file instead of thrid party tools

Comment: @John your file is a standard Acumatica report that you want to print to the Zebra printer? Have you tried to print it from a PDF version manually, and does that give you acceptable performance? You are right about the carrier shipment labels; you could generate ZPL like that yourself by using the Zebra designer...

Comment: @Gabriel John and I work together so he was writing here as well. It's the same need where we developed our barcode tags for our items in the report designer not realizing that our current zebra tag printers accept zpl format printing. We prefer not to have redo the layouts and logic that we have in the report designer. So we were trying to preserve our work. So it's still technically a barcode that is bring printed with a little more information around it. if we can't preserve, it seems our only options is to create zpl files. You referenced using the zebra designer, how would that work?

Comment: I have custom code that generates the ZPL that I need to print.  When I run through the custom report, it produces the report as a PDF rendering of my ZPL.  I can print to a laser printer, but my barcode printer complains about PDF.  Assuming this is the RAW checkbox issue noted above.  If I do PXRedirectToFileException, won't I simply get redirected to my file and my client has to know how to handle the file?  Won't this prevent printing labels from a mobile device using device hub.  Is there a way to configure the report to produce the output in a RAW format instead?

Comment: @BrianStevens not clear to me how a ZPL could actually be previewed and printed to a laser printer... for shipment labels the ZPL file is attached to the Packages tab in the individual packages line, and it can't be viewed on screen at all. Can you share the ZPL file somehow and screenshots/code of how you send the print job to the print queue?

Comment: I am creating the ZPL commands for output to the printer.  If I cheat and send it directly to the printer (for testing, a local printer off the web server) then I can send the codes directly to produce my barcode label.  When I output the same codes as an Acumatica report, I just get the text of my raw label file when I run the report manually.  When I try hooking that in on Device Hub, it complains that the raw mode printer cannot print pdf - but the report is literally the text of my ZPL commands for the printer (intended).

Comment: I could be completely missing the concepts.  I know we can generate the ZPL file of all the commands for the printer and have the client download it is a file to be processed by a batch file to automatically print.  However, if I man the storeroom with mobile devices, they cannot process the downloaded label file with a batch file - the desire for device hub.  When I create a report that contains my ZPL commands for the printer, I get a pdf of the commands when I want a raw text file of the commands to be sent to the printer.  I need to send raw to device hub, and clearly I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Too much for a comment - posted as a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340895/how-can-i-print-custom-zpl-labels-from-a-mobile-device-to-a-printer-connected-to