# How can I print custom ZPL labels from a mobile device to a printer connected to device hub?

Tags: acumatica

I want to allow our storeroom attendants to perform routine tasks with a mobile device, which will include receiving packages and printing custom location and item labels in addition to a variety of custom tags for various uses.  Device hub in **Acumatica 2018R2** seems to be the perfect concept to enable this, but I cannot understand how to send a **custom ZPL file** to Device Hub.

It appears that `PickPackShip` does this with carrier labels, sending them to device hub behind the scenes from what I can read, but I don't have carrier labels configured and available to me and can't catch how it is sending the label file to device hub - looks like it sends the file to the browser instead, as I read the code.

When I create my own custom ZPL label file, how do I send that raw text file to device hub?

I can create a string of my label data and print it directly to a printer connected to the application server, but that breaks **"cloud"** rules.
I can create a report that prints my ZPL code and have device hub print that text (apparently as a PDF) to my laser printer. 
I can setup the printer in device hub as a raw printer, but running the report to device hub results in the error on Device Hub `"Print job 7 contains a PDF file that can't be sent in raw mode".` 
It appears sending it as an **Acumatica** report converts my text ZPL codes into a PDF document first, and I can't sort out how to send the raw command text file.

ZPL Label Data (can be seen when running the report manually):

```
^FO0,30^A0N,32,0^FDCHEMICAL, TEST^FS
^FO0,62^A0N,28,0^FD^FS
^FO0,85^BQN,2,5,Q^FDQA,18-00001^FS
^FO120,90^A0N,32,0^FD18-00001^FS
^FO120,120^A0N,20,0^FDStk UM: PIECE^FS
^FO120,142^A0N,20,0^FDSO UM: PIECE^FS
^FO120,164^A0N,20,0^FD^FS
^FO120,185^A0N,16,0^FD03/22/2019^FS
^PQ1,0,0,N
^XZ
```

Printing as a report to Device Hub:

```
Dictionary<string, string> printParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
printParams["SSLBLabel.LabelID"] = graphLB.Labels.Current.LabelID.ToString();

PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, "SS601000", printParams);

PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobForRawFile(adapter, new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchPrinter, SONotificationSource.Customer, "SS601000",
    Base.Accessinfo.BranchID, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "LabelID", sSLBLabel.LabelID.ToString() } },
    PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix(SSCS.LB.Messages.PrintLabels, "Label"));

PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobGroup("ZEBRA", ex, "Labels"); //Job1
```

Printer configuration on Device Hub:

[image: 1]

When I use an **"illegal"** method of printing directly to a printer visible to the application server, the ZPL data provided results in a proper test label. I don't mind creating an actual file to send into Device Hub, but all the examples I see appear to merge the labels into 1 file and then redirect the browser to download the file instead of having device hub mange the raw label.

Comment: Removing the PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobForRawFile part did not change my results. Is that where the magic is to send the label file to Device Hub via something like a notification?  I realized that I'm running my report twice, effectively, I think.  But CreatePrintJobForRawFile has a bool output, so it must be doing something self-contained in there.  No source code or documentation that I have found so far.

Comment: RAW mode should be used for printing ZPL files but the reports are of PDF types. PickPackShip sends the ZPL file returned by the carrier to the thermal printer. If your thermal printer supports PDF you would still have to declare it as non RAW for it to print PDF files like reports.

Comment: Makes sense, but how do I send MY labels to the zpl printer?  Can I not use device hub for custom ZPL label files?  I am trying to send raw ZPL commands.

Comment: ZPL file has to be uploaded in Acumatica database. After it's uploaded, you pass the file ID to CreatePrintJobForRawFile. Open Source Code page in Acumatica and look up source code of method "SOShipmentEntry.PrintCarrierLabels", it has an example.

Comment: The key is to pass only the hardcoded FILEID parameter to CreatePrintJobForRawFile Dictionary<string, string> { { "FILEID", zplFile.UID.ToString() } }

Comment: Thanks, HB.  I have the file uploading, and the targetUrl variable can be pasted into the address bar to retrieve my label data. I replaced "new NotificationUtility(this).SearchPrinter" in the CreatePrintJobForRawFile call with a new function GetPrinter to return my printer name ZEBRA, thinking this would be necessary to tell device hub where to print.  Device hub does not report that the file was sent  Seems like I must be close, but I'm stuck again.  What triggers sending the job to the device hub?

Comment: There's a push mechanism (notification) which DeviceHub register to. I don't know much about the details of that mechanism but there's other stuff you can check before that. The call to CreatePrintJobForRawFile should create a record in SMPrintJob table (Acumatica used to/still have? a Print Job page where you can see them). If it's in there then it should be picked up by device hub assuming everything else is configured properly.

Comment: Also check in table SMPrintJobParameter, it should contain the single parameter FILEID along with parameter value that is the ID of the ZPL file.

Comment: I see records in both tables.  8 in each.  They show in Print Jobs as Failed status.  Nothing shows in my device hub window.   [database records](http://prntscr.com/n2tzm7)

Comment: Nevermind.  They are not the ones from CreateRaw.  The date on most are from Friday before implementing what you suggested.  It seems that I am not creating the needed print jobs, so I must have an error in the call to CreatePrintJobForRawFile.

Comment: I tried something else and got a print job created and passed to the printer via devicemanager…  **PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint printJobGraph = (PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint)PXGraph.CreateInstance(typeof(PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint));
printJobGraph.AddPrintJob("Label Test", "ZEBRA", SOReports.PrintLabels, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FILEID", labelFileInfo.UID.ToString() } }, null);**
I can retrieve the file from the database and pass directly to the printer, but device hub does not result in a label.  Any ideas on how to see what device hub is sending?

Comment: That will not create a raw file, you need to call CreatePrintJobForRawFile instead of  AddPrintJob and first parameter should be adapter and third parameter should be Customer: PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobForRawFile(adapter, new NotificationUtility(this).SearchPrinter, SONotificationSource.Customer, SOReports.PrintLabels, Accessinfo.BranchID, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FILEID", mergedFile.UID.ToString() } },

Comment: I have been trying that, but it never creates a print job.  Is it because I do not have carrier labels enabled or defined?

Comment: Yes there are validations: PXAccess.FeatureInstalled(DeviceHubFeatureName) && adapter != null && IsSupported(adapter), first mean activate devicehub in features

Comment: This is the second condition: adapter.MassProcess || adapter.QuickProcessFlow != PXQuickProcess.ActionFlow.NoFlow

Comment: What determines "IsSupported(adapter)?  I set **adapter.MassProcess = true;** and Device Hub (and even Carrier Labels although not configured) is enabled in my DEV instance.  Is it locked down to specific screens that allowed to output to devicehub?  If so, is there a method that I can override to add my screens, similar to how we add screens for approval workflows (i.e. EPApprovalMapMaint.GetEntityTypeScreens)?

Comment: That is all the validation I see. To test built in raw file printing attach one ZPL or ZPII files to SOPackageDetail record in shipment screen. Then try to use the Print Labels action. It's better to disable device hub while doing that so you can see the job in the table, if it gets picked up and printed by device hub it will disappear. If you can't print with that you likely have some configuration issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been 18 months since I asked the question, so there may or may not have been a fix in an Acumatica version upgrade.  I am now on Acumatica ERP 2019R2.  After the file is uploaded into Acumatica, use *PXGraph.CreateInstance().CreatePrintJob* to print the raw file to the printer on Device Hub.  You need the Dictionary parameter for FILEID as HB stated, some description for the print job (this ultimately flows into the Windows Print Queue) and a PrintSettings object to define the printer to use.

```
protected void DHPrint(PXAdapter adapter, FileInfo mergedFile, SMPrinter printer)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters =
        new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FILEID", mergedFile.UID.ToString() } };
    string description = "Label";
    PrintSettings printSettings = new PrintSettings() {
        PrinterID = printer.PrinterID,
        NumberOfCopies = 1,
        PrintWithDeviceHub = true,
        DefinePrinterManually = false };
    PXGraph.CreateInstance<SMPrintJobMaint>().CreatePrintJob(
        printSettings,
        (string)null,
        parameters,
        description);
}
```

Thanks to Hugues Beauséjour for the assist.